# Counterclockwise installation getting stuck at 42%

Tags: eclipse, plugins, clojure

I wanted to install counterclockwise plugin on my eclipse, but after I finish with wizard installation, it starts out normally, however it gets stuck at 42% and after a while I get this message:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:
 (profile=epp.package.java,
 phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at 
  http://ccw.cgrand.net/updatesite/plugins/ccw.branding_0.5.0.STABLE002.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at 
  http://ccw.cgrand.net/updatesite/plugins/ccw.clojure_1.2.0.STABLE13.jar.
Read timed out
```

Comment: Did you retry? It seems like a network problem ar first sight. Can you acccess http://ccw.cgrand.net/updatesite/plugins/ ?

Comment: Tried several times, also checked connection its fine(and i can access ccw.cgrand.net/update/plugins just fine from brwser)

Comment: There is related question to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139796/counterclockwise-installed-no-effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this really looks there is a problem with connection to the repository. (re-try later, or check your connection, proxies, firewall, etc...)

There is a beautiful tutorial for

1) Using Eclipse + Clojure with Leiningen (CCW)

http://bit.ly/yd4AW1

2) integrating Leiningen with eclipse (which is very handy)

http://bit.ly/goeIT4

Hope it helps!